# Finding my Screenshots in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have taken many screenshots on Minecraft Java edition, but I can't find them in the screenshots folder on my computer. Can you please help me? (I have Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Open up your windows explorer and go to:

```
C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\screenshots
```

This is where all of your screenshots should be.